# Save Multiple index array value in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to save my array with multiple indexing array values.
Demo code

```
Array
(
    [CodeConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [IsDirty] => 
                )
        )
    [ObjectAccountConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [IsDirty] => 2
                )
        )
    [TaxConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 2
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

I want to save this array values direct into table .Table name is audit_trail_details.
so please suggest mi proper solution for how to save this data into table.

Comment: please look arround(saveAssociated) here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: hello sir,I want to save this data from appcontroller direct into audit_trail_details table.

Comment: You are asking different question base on same array sample please affert more from your side ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use saveAssociated and parse your array as the first parameter:-

```
$this->AuditTrailDetail->saveAssociated($data);
```

You will also need to make sure $data contains the AuditTrailDetail you are saving the associated data against. For example:-

```
Array
(
    [AuditTrailDetail] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )
    [CodeConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [IsDirty] => 
                )
        )
    [ObjectAccountConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [IsDirty] => 2
                )
        )
    [TaxConfiguration] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 2
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                )
        )
)
```